# Add custom validation directive to ol element

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am working with template driven forms. I have a list that I call ngFor on, inside a ngIf. I would like to validate that this list is non-empty.

my html looks like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div *nfIf="predicate"
        <ol validateNotEmpty>
            <li *ngFor"let item of items">
                <input name="item-{{i.id}}" [(ngModel)]="item.text">
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my custom validation directive looks like this:

```
import {Attribute, Directive, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[validateNotEmpty]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => NotEmptyValidatorDirective), multi: true }
    ]
})

export class NotEmptyValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        console.log("Firing");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know it is hooked up correctly, because when I put the directive on the form or input element, it fires like it should. I can make it fire when I modify the ol element as such:

```
<ol name="listname" validateNotEmpty [ngModel]="items" ngDefaultControl>
```

But it fires before the change has taken place, so it is not really useful for me. So how can I make the validator on the native ol element fire when the length of items change?

Comment: it will always fire but what you do with the abstract control that matters you need to write the logic there what you are saying is add a directive dynamically on length change that is not possible

Comment: You could try using a ngModelGroup. That would be the "built in" way to handle validation on a group of controls. https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModelGroup

Comment: But that is model / reaction driven approach, right? Or am i mistaken?